# use ExportBuildingComponent in Design Automation for Inventor

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

we can run a local Inventor add-in for convert a iam assembly to RFA, using ExportBuildingComponent API.

As explained in documentation (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/troubleshooting/#inventor) this method is not available, instead you suggest an export to SAT and an import to RFA from Revit design automation instance.

Is planned the update of Inventor design automation engines to expose the ExportBuildingComponent API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That section needs to be removed from the documentation (pinged my colleagues about that) as **RFA** export **is** available now on **Design Automation API for Inventor**:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/revit-core-engine-now-available-design-automation-inventor

It's also used by our main configurator sample application: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-configurator-inventor/tree/master/AppBundles/RFAExportRCEPlugin